# Windows Explorer: show image dimensions in status bar

Tags: images, windows-explorer, statusbar

Windows XP normally shows the dimensions of image files in the status bar when they are selected.

However this has stopped working on one machine I use, the dimensions are still shown in the details section of the sidebar.

Does anyone know how to turn this functionality on or off?

Comment: are the default programs that open the image files on both PCs the same?

Comment: yes @jay , both machines are set to use "Windows picture and fax viewer".

Comment: check that both are using same folder settings, ie Pictures not Documents or General. Source: http://www.thewinforums.com/threads/50939-Resolved-Image-dimensions-in-folder-explorer-status-bar

Comment: @jay both are set to the same `folder template` ie, pictures / documents, and neither of those options enables the dimensions in the status bar. strange

Answer (score 1):

A shell-extension has taken over the metadata-handler. You can try to determine which one it is and disable/uninstall it, but an easier soltuion to fix it is to simply re-register the default image handler by running the following command:

```
regsvr32 shimgvw.dll
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, 30 months after the question was asked, though I don't actually use this machine anymore!

Comment: Maybe not, but others might find your question through a search engine. I did. (Content on the Internet is immortal.)